# FuncAnimation printing first image only

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a 3D array in python using the first dimension as time.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, as I recieve no error with this code. But my animation is stationary, stuck on the first page of the array.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

array = np.random.random(size=(10, 20, 30))
empty = np.zeros(array[0].shape)

fig = plt.figure()
mat = plt.imshow(empty)
def func(i):
    mat.set_data(array[i])
    return mat
frames = len(array)
FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames)
plt.show()
```

I'd like the use the below code but I haven't seen an annonymous function used anywhere with FuncAnimation. It produces the same result except `mat` is not created setting the initial `axes`.

```
fig = plt.figure()
func = lambda i: plt.imshow(array[i])
frames = len(array)
FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between your code and any example you find on matplotlib animations is that you do not actually store the `FuncAnimation`. Depending on how you run things it would then directly be garbage-collected.

```
ani = FuncAnimation(...)
```