# FuncAnimation displays only one frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use FuncAnimation, but encounter the problem that it stops after displaying only a single frame.

This problem has been posted before on StackOverflow,

[Python Matplotlib FuncAnimation only draws one frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745391/python-matplotlib-funcanimation-only-draws-one-frame)

[FuncAnimation printing first image only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599002/funcanimation-printing-first-image-only)

However, the solution there -- to give a reference to the animation object -- does not do the trick in my case and in both cases leaves blank plots when I plot them.

To give an example, I would expect this code, taken from
https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/23558/basic-animation-with-funcanimation
to animate a red particle tracing out a sine curve.

However, in my case the red particle gets stuck at t=0. After running the code below, number_of_calls has been increased to 1, and so animate() has only been called once. For reference, I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

TWOPI = 2*np.pi

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.arange(0.0, TWOPI, 0.001)
s = np.sin(t)
l = plt.plot(t, s)

ax = plt.axis([0,TWOPI,-1,1])

redDot, = plt.plot([0], [np.sin(0)], 'ro')

number_of_calls=0

def animate(i):

    global number_of_calls

    redDot.set_data(i, np.sin(i))
    number_of_calls+=1
    return redDot,

# create animation using the animate() function
myAnimation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.arange(0.0, TWOPI, 0.1), \
                                      interval=10, blit=True, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The code works fine for me. I suspect it's a backend problem. Which backend are you using?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. I'm executing the code in Jupyter, loaded from anaconda-navigator. The underlying Python version is 3.6.5. Does that address your question about the backend I'm using? Otherwise, how can I check it?

Comment: `plt.get_backend()`. Anyways, the fact that you use jupyter answers this. Jupyter inline backend produces a static png image, right? So that cannot have moving dots in it.

Comment: I'm puzzled: in lecture 4 at https://machine-learning-for-physicists.org/
from 26:04 and onwards, the slides show the progressive learning of an image by a neural network, using FuncAnimation, and run in Jupyter.

The code above is a shorter example of the code in the lecture, but seems to have the same feature in my version of Jupyter.

So Jupyter does seem to be able to do animation. I wonder if the issue can be resolved by loading some additional library or perhaps adding some additional code?

Comment: I closed this question as duplicate of a question where you find all your options. (See yellow box)

Comment: Indeed, setting (e.g.) ``%matplotlib notebook`` before loading matplotlib solves my problem for the above code. (And ``%matplotlib tk`` for the code in the lectures. Thanks for your help, ImportanceOfBeingEarnest!